Trying to have multiple Input boxes in one window using CustomTinker
I am fairly new to programming. Anyway, I am trying to create a code where I make my program input new boxes after they press ok. Right now it's just opening into a new window.
How do I make this so that it's in one window, and a new input box just shows up instead?
Here is my code:
import yfinance as yf
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter


customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")


root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.title('tkinter.com-CustomTkinter Input Window')
root.geometry = ('400x200')

def input():

    dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text=' Stock Ticker' , title='Stock Name')

    dateInput = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text = 'Please Enter Start Date Here: YYYY-MM-DD', title= 'Start Date')
    end_date = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text = 'Please Enter End Date Here: YYYY-MM-DD', title = 'End Date')

    global thing
    thing = dialog.get_input()
    if thing:
        my_label.configure(text=f"Hello: {thing}")
    else:
        my_label.configure(text=f'You forgot to write')

        global date1
        date1 = dateInput.get_input()
        if date1:
            my_label.configure(text=f"Hello: {date1}")
        else:
            my_label.configure(text=f'You forgot to write')

    global date_end
    date_end = end_date.get_input()
    if date_end:
        my_label.configure(text=f"Hello: {date_end}")
    else:
        my_label.configure(text=f'You forgot to write')




my_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text = "Click Me", command = input)
my_button.pack(pady = 40)

my_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text='')
my_label.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()


Use Entry to make an input field in the current window, don't use a dialog box.

You can create a custom dialog using CTkToplevel.


How do I make this so that it's in one window, and a new input box
just shows up instead?

The problem can be fixed.

Don't use the keyword input for a function. Use underscores or any
other different name.
Don't use global.
Use CTkInputDialog for each if/else condition block.

You ready to go.
Snippet modified:
def _input():

    dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text=' Stock Ticker' , title='Stock Name')
    thing = dialog.get_input()
    if thing:
        my_label.configure(text=f"Hello: {thing}")
    else:
        my_label.configure(text=f'You forgot to write enter number')

    #global date1
    dateInput = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text = 'Please Enter Start Date Here: YYYY-MM-DD', title= 'Start Date')
    date1 = dateInput.get_input()
    if date1:
         my_label.configure(text=f"Hello: {date1}")
    else:
        my_label.configure(text=f'You forgot to write start date')

    #global date_end
    
    end_date = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text = 'Please Enter End Date Here: YYYY-MM-DD', title = 'End Date')
    date_end = end_date.get_input()
    if date_end:
        
         my_label.configure(text=f"Hello: {date_end}")
    else:
         my_label.configure(text=f'You forgot to write end date')

Screenshot:

